# Any alternative to bad UX when changing color styles in Figma?

Tags: usability

Figma works fine until you need to change a color styles in your designs. It's absolute nightmare. You have to select an element, click on color style on the right panel, click on «edit style» icon and choose a new color. 4 click just for changing one color value. When you have a design system and a lot of styles it can take days to repaint everything. So I'm looking for any alternatives or more convenient ways of changing colors in your designs. Maybe someone knows a plugin or something that can make this process easier?

Comment: Would the [Themer plugin](https://www.figma.com/community/plugin/731176732337510831/Themer) solve your problem?

Comment: You know you can create custom colour styles right? So you have your own palette of colours that you can name things like BRAND1 and use that on your CTAs and logos etc. Then, if the colour value for BRAND1 changes you edit the colour palette and everything using that colour style automatically updates to the new value.

Answer (score 2):

Figma has a built-in feature for creating, managing, and updating color styles called [Styles](https://help.figma.com/hc/en-us/articles/360038746534-Create-color-text-effect-and-layout-grid-styles).

You essentially create a color swatch in one place, and then use it wherever you need to throughout your design system. If you need to adjust it, you adjust the root style and it will update everywhere you've used it. You can do this for text and effects like drop shadow as well.

I'd highly recommend running through all of the [Figma tutorials](https://help.figma.com/hc/en-us/categories/6448726686615-Tutorials) on their website to make sure you're making the most of all the built-in features. Figma's a great tool and they do a good job of tailoring features to make designing more efficient.

Answer (score -1):

Your point on **Figma's changing color style** process is definitely appreciative from designer's perspective. Congrats for that!

I want to share my opinion so that you can rethink and get works done with less pressure in mind. You already know the famous Tesler’s law which states that,

> If you simplify something, you will consistently transfer that
> complexity to another area.

For example, you can eliminate the steps to repaint everything, but on the other hand, you are making yourself adopt with another process which will increase cognitive load of your task whereas you're already adopted to the Figma's default process of changing colour style.

And as far as I know, there is no plugin or more convenient ways of changing colours alternative to Figma's default process.